# I am trying to make a trigger in mysql, but not working

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

Here s my trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER after_changing_student_year
        AFTER UPDATE ON student_details
        FOR EACH ROW 
        BEGIN
               SET @old_stud_id = NEW.student_id;
               INSERT INTO assigned_groups (student_id) VALUES (@old_stud_id);
        END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I used mysql variable because direct assignment wasn't working.

But I found this one is working:

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER after_changing_student_year
        AFTER UPDATE ON student_details
        FOR EACH ROW 
        BEGIN
               INSERT INTO assigned_groups (student_id) VALUES (83);
        END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I also found that renaming student_id column in assigned_groups to student_id_1 will work, but that's not a feasible solution as i have to make many triggers like this.

EDIT: Sorry guys, it turn out to be some problem with my PHP code. When i edit directly in mysql,  trigger works correctly. But not when I update it through PHP code. What might be the issue?

Comment: Why was direct assignment not working?

Comment: For the 1st case declare a variable before the loop as `DECLARE old_stud_id  int;` Then use this variable to set the value as `set old_stud_id = NEW.student_id;` and then this variable in insert query value. For the column name change that you mentioned, not sure since it does not make any sense.

Comment: @fancyPants No idea, thats why i tried variable.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Can you show me an example? I tried to put Just before for each and also before Delimiter..

Comment: Well (also @AbhikChakraborty), it also doesn't make sense to assign the value to a variable first and not using it directly. It would be new to me, if MySQL wouldn't throw an error if something's not working.

Comment: Guys, please consider this also: "I also found that renaming student_id column in assigned_groups to student_id_1 will work, but that's not a feasible solution as i have to make many triggers like this."

Comment: Since you don't use keywords as column names, this tells me that you're just confusing your test cases or you simply have typos or something like that. All in all you don't provide information necessary to solve the problem.

Comment: @fancyPants See, when i give `INSERT INTO assigned_groups (student_id) VALUES (83);` it is correctly working. The prob occurs only when i use `NEW.student_id`.

Comment: Is it due to assigned_groups and student_details have columns with same name `student_id`?

Comment: No, the code you provided should work. And an even better way is to not use variables, just like juergen_d's answer, which he deleted, because you said, you already tried that. The thing is, that there should be an error message, if it really doesn't work. But you don't provide it, so we can't help. I don't know what you messed up, maybe you're testing on another database and haven't realized and check on another? Whatever the reason...provide more info or we can't help.

Comment: @fancyPants You want me to post mysql log messages?

Comment: A small [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e8bd/1) that may be useful to clarify the situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, I tested and it is working:

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER after_changing_student_year
        AFTER UPDATE ON student_details
        FOR EACH ROW 
        BEGIN
          DECLARE old_stud_id INT;
               SET old_stud_id = NEW.student_id;
               INSERT INTO assigned_groups (student_id) VALUES (old_stud_id);
        END$$
DELIMITER ;
```